# Can I generate actionscript classes from XSD for XML serialization/deserialization?

Tags: xml, apache-flex, actionscript, xsd

I've been looking at various questions in StackOverflow and in other sites, but I have not seen a library that 
a) generates actionscript code given XSD
b) serializes to and deserializes from XML using the generated classes.

In Java world this is JAXB. I have a set of large XSDs, based on which a web service is producing XML output. I don't want to write actionscript classes by hand, that'd be huge piece of work.

Having source code in actionscript would help a lot, since writing code based on runtime binding of xml/json to objects is much more error prone compared to having proxy like classes. Any ideas?

update: I've found a wizard in Adobe's Flash Builder for doing what I've been looking for, but unfortunately, it died on me complaining about case sensitivity of entities and services names etc. So a 3rd party framework which can do this is still required.

Comment: I have written a DSL and ActionScript generator in XText/XPand2 using the eclipse Modeling Framework, mainly for generating all sorts of data models, XML parsing and output, and the server side counterparts in PHP/EJB3 and MySQL, just from a description of the data.  It's not perfect, but it helps a lot and pretty much does what I gather you are trying to do.  Now, since this is obviously a rather limited approach, and it does not fit on a lot of existing web services, I'm curious about your solution.  Did you find anything? If not, I'd be interested in starting an Open Source project...

Comment: I have not found a reliable solution. As I've written: the solution i Flash builder died on me, so this is still an unresolved issue for me.

Comment: After all, i still could not find a way. Any news ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try out [asaxb](https://github.com/piercer/ASAXB). It allows you to unmarshall XML into ActionScript objects based on metadata.  It is at least part of the solution.